# Logstash not replacing "%type" with value

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Hello I have this configuration for a logstash running on my computer :

```
input {
    exec {
        command => "powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -f scripts/windows/process.ps1 command logstash"
        interval => 30
        type => "process_data"
        codec => line
        tags => [ logstash" ]
    }
}

output
{
    if "sometype-logs" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        doc_as_upsert => true
        index => "sometype-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        hosts => "locahost:9200"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
} else {
    elasticsearch {
    action => "index"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    index => "%{type}"
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    template_overwrite => true
}
}
```

When displaying indexes I have :

[image]

Why is index name is "%type" and not "process_data" ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably just something about syntax. To used some field of the data, you must use this syntax

> %{[somefield]}

(see example on this documentation [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.9/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html))

So, in your case, try this :

```
"%{[type]}"
```

in place of

```
"%{type}"
```